# combining a variable with a link and making it href under php

Tags: php

i'm trying to do something like this in php:

```
    echo "<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$link">watch here</a>";
```

i have the video id's in $link and i want to combine it with http://www.youtube.com/watch?v= and send the user to that video when "watch here" is clicked. it gives the error

```
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in xxxxxxxxxx on line xxx
```

i'm pretty new to php, please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot mix single quotes with double quotes, you escape the quotes around link or transform then in single quote.

Comment: @MihaiIorga is correct.
It should be like  echo "<a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$link'>watch here</a>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using single quotes for echo:

```
echo '<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $link . '">watch here</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you have double quotes in double quoted string
this should fix it:

```
echo "<a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$link'>watch here</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the errors using a backslash before the double quotes in your content like the following:

```
$link = 'h8f7ewhfg';
echo "<a href=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={$link}\">watch here</a>";
```